# How to use travis with multiple OS's + docker in a Matrix config

Tags: docker, deployment, travis-ci, continuous-deployment, travis-ci-cli

I am developing an opensource and multi-platform. I run tests on Travis to test and generate builds on these different platforms.

To use multiple OS's I have the following in my `travis.yml` file:

`matrix:
  include:
    - os: linux
      dist: trusty
      sudo: required
      language: python
      python: 3.6.2
    - os: osx
      sudo: required
    - os: windows
      language: python
      sudo: required
      python: 3.6.2
script:
  - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" != "windows" ]]; then python3 myProject; fi`

How do I add docker in this matrix?

The documentation says this:

`services:
  - docker`

But can I put this also in my travis.yml file?

And how do I only execute certain commands in the docker instance?

For the different OS's I use 
`- if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" != "windows" ]]; then python3 myProject; fi`, how do I use this if function for docker?

There is enough documentation about Docker, and multi-os. But not for combining Docker and multiple os's. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`dist: trusty` and `sudo: required` give you Docker. There is no need to add `services: [docker]`. https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/ is misleading in that both are shown in the same YAML snippet. That should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is currently not possible with Travis as I was not able to find any hack to run docker on macos on travis.

Let me know if you find one.